# What's the difference between deferred scripts and scripts placed at the end of the page body?

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications

HTML5 introduced the `defer` attribute for scripts whose loading can be deferred in a HTML page. `defer` may be used for any scripts that don't need to be loaded before the DOM (a.k.a don't mess with the DOM before it is ready).

For a long time web developers have been advised to put all scripts that don't need to be loaded before the DOM not in the page `head` but before the end of the `body` tag instead.

What is the difference between the use of `defer` and the long practiced advise? Does the first substitute the latter?

I appreciate any answer. Thank you.

Comment: I believe script is still going to be downloaded even if you use defer, and it may slow done overall page load

Comment: The idea behind putting script at the bottom is not only to delay execution, but also to delay download

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Both async and defer scripts begin to download immediately without pausing the parser and both support an optional onload handler to address the common need to perform initialization which depends on the script.

From the [WebKit blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20160406104657/https://webkit.org/blog/1395/running-scripts-in-webkit/), so the behaviour is not necessarily the same across all browsers.  So, performance would be better if the scripts are still at the end, as they will be downloaded later.

Edit 2017: browser support is now much better, so you can probably get away with async/defer scripts in the head.  It's still probably a safer choice to put them at the bottom; new browsers will still download them early even if they're not in the head.

Edit 2020: These days, unless you're supporting *very* old browsers, you should just go ahead and use async/defer in the head.

Comment: Why would performance be better when the scripts are downloaded later? Wouldn't the performance be better when the scripts are downloaded as soon as possible?

Comment: @RuudLenders because at the time support was patchy and so many browsers would download the scripts immediately and this would block rendering until the script was downloaded and executed.  Support is much better now four and a half years later, but the difference in the time that the browser will start downloading is tiny (if any, with preparsing) so I'd still put them at the end of the body.